# Youtube Jquery Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I want to display the youtube channel video in my site. So I have been looking for Jquery Plugin

This Features should contains,

1. Adding More Playlist
2. Search functionality
3. Sorting functionality
4. Comment section
5. Social Media Share

I have tried many jquery plugin, but few feature is missing in any plugin.

Please suggest me the plugin, which contains all features.

Thank you

Comment: You can create one using their api.

Comment: Am a beginner, How do i create this. please guide me

Comment: You can start by doing this: https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/youtube

Comment: okay thank you envision. I will start work on this